# Would mortals in the Percy Jackson universe be able to defeat monsters with their weaponry and knowledge, if they could see through the Mist?

Tags: percy-jackson

If the normal humans in the *Percy Jackson* universe could look through the Mist, would they be able to defeat or control the monsters with the knowledge and weaponry they have?

Monsters can be defeated in a variety of ways. Celestial Bronze, Stygian Iron, and Imperial Gold are the most commonly used methods of killing monsters, but monsters can also be killed through drowning and getting smashed too hard.

Would the mortals be able to defeat monsters in a war?

What about the Titans and Giants? (Okay, giants can only be defeated by gods and demigods, but could humans control/capture a giant?)

Answer (score 4):

**Monsters; yes.**

*Technically*, regular humans can defeat monsters, if they have access to Celestial Bronze or another blessed metal. We see this with Dr. Chase at the end of *The Titan's Curse*:

> Just as the army of monsters came over the hill, a Sopwith Camel swooped down out of the sky.
>   "Get away from my daughter!" Dr. Chase called down, and his machine guns burst to life, peppering the ground with bullet holes and startling the whole group of monsters into scattering.
>   "Dad?" yelled Annabeth in disbelief.
>   "Run!" he called back, his voice growing fainter as the biplane swooped by.
>   [...]
>   The Sopwith Camel swooped down again. A few giants threw javelins, and one flew straight between the wings of the plane, but the machine guns blazed. I realized with amazement that somehow Dr. Chase must've gotten hold of celestial bronze to fashion his bullets. The first row of snake women wailed as the machine gun's volley blew them into sulfurous yellow powder.
>   <sub>*Percy Jackson and the Olympians*, book 3: *The Titan's Curse*, chapter 17: "I Put On A Few Million Extra Pounds"</sub>

**Titans; probably not.**

Titans is a bit of a harder question; I'm tempted to say no, as you need godly forces battling them to be able to combat the Titans' own powers. As we see in *The Last Olympian*, Morpheus is able to put all the mortals to sleep, but the demigods remain awake. You'd need some godly power on your side to be able to defeat them.

**Giants; no.**

As for the giants, definitely not; you need a demigod and a god working together to defeat them, and they also have powers akin to gods and Titans. The giants would be able to break out; they can't really be contained, even by demigods.

Comment: what about capturing and controlling them like Megatron in Transformers or like Dinosaurs in Jurassic Park/World. I mean giants are max 13 meters, with the right rope you could bind them. They may would need to control special abilities like burning(Titan: krios i think)--- And what if Mortals wouldn't have access to Celestial Bronze(CB), etc?

Comment: Correction: Not Krios, Hyperion is burning. If human could permanently cool him he couldbe captured.

Comment: Morpheus is a god. I didnt ment fighting him... Humans would definetly lose against gods. Humans would lose against morpheus(sleep), or Hades (army) or Poseidon(earthquakes and tsunamis) or just gaia. Humans really dont  have a chance against gods

Comment: @Jannis - Morpheus sided with the Titans; once you're talking about fighting a war, you have to take allies into account.

Comment: I'm not asking in the context of the 5th book. Im asking about the general chance of mortals to defeat or capturing and imprison Monster/Giants/Titans when they could see through the mist, even without having Celestial Bronze etc. But we can agree gods cant be slayed by mortals...